# Do you know why it console logs twice, when I add an item?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

This is a simple note app build with angular and firebase. The main components are adding items and displaying items. In my `ngOnInit()` hook, I put `console.log(this.notepads)` right after getting all data from the service. The problem is that when I add an item, it logs twice as you can see in the uploaded screenshot.

I think my `ngOnInit()` is being called twice every time I add an item. What do you guys think?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotepadService } from 'src/app/services/notepad.service';
import { Notepad } from 'src/app/model/note';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-note',
  templateUrl: './add-note.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-note.component.css']
})
export class AddNoteComponent implements OnInit {
  title:boolean=false;
  noteTitle:string;
  noteDescription:string;
  constructor(private notepadService:NotepadService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if(!this.title || !this.noteTitle) {
      alert('Task is empty')
    } else {
    let note:Notepad = {
      title:this.noteTitle,
      description:this.noteDescription
    }
    this.noteTitle = ''
    this.noteDescription = ''
    this.title = false
    this.notepadService.addNote(note)
  }
}
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NotepadService } from 'src/app/services/notepad.service';
import { Notepad } from 'src/app/model/note';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-notepad',
  templateUrl: './notepad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notepad.component.css']
})
export class NotepadComponent implements OnInit {
  notepads:Notepad[]=[];
  modal:boolean=false;
  selectedNote:Notepad= {
    id:'',
    title: '',
    description: ''
  };
  constructor(private notepadService:NotepadService) { 
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notepadService.getNotepads().subscribe(notepad=> {
      this.notepads=notepad
      console.log(this.notepads)
    })

  }

  onSelect(note:Notepad){
    this.modal = !this.modal
    this.selectedNote = note;
  }

  onSubmit(reg:NgForm) {
    const note = reg.value;
    note.id = this.selectedNote.id
    this.notepadService.updateNote(note)
    this.modal = false

  }
  removeNote() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.notepadService.deleteNote(this.selectedNote)
      this.modal = false
    }
    this.modal = false

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NotePadService` is probably of the [observable] type which means that when a property of the observable changes the UI/(in this case your console log) is updated automatically. Resulting in two console logs.

```
// subscribe() is a method of the Observable type. This is a utility that asynchronously or synchronously streams data to a variety of components or services that have subscribed to the observable.

this.notepadService.getNotepads().subscribe(notepad=> {
      this.notepads=notepad
      console.log(this.notepads)
    })
```

You have assigned the observable here(look at the constructor):

```
private notepadService:NotepadService
```

When you initially load the page `notpadservice` gets called a console log occurs.

Then when you add a note property of the observable is updated resulting in another console log.

Answering your question on whether the `ngOnInit()` is being called twice.

> No since the two console logs occur due to the [observable] type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. Do you know how to prevent it? Does it make performance worse?

Comment: There is no way to prevent this from happening as you are using an incorrect data type. Use another data type or use a method of getting data from an observable. Consider marking the answer as correct if you found it useful.